# Change varchar type (of MySQL ) in SWI-Prolog

Tags: mysql, swi-prolog

Can anyone help me with converting varchar type(of MySQL column) to utf8_general_ci in SWI-Prolog?

I've tried this

```
:-module(utf8_general_ci).
```

But still doesn't recognize the language of the value.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the encoding type of Prolog.. So i use

```
 :- encoding(utf8).
```

and know everything is ok.